# "Reference does not exist" warning with \includeonly

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, include

I am in the process of writing my thesis and am using the `\include` command to separate the files. But when I use the `\includeonly` command to select on the current chapter which has references to figures, theorems and `algorithm2e` code blocks in other chapters, I get the correct references in the output PDF file along with this warning:

```
name{..} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

Based on all I have read upon on `\includeonly`, I don't think this is its expected behavior. This is the that preamble I am using.

```
\documentclass[pdftex,11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\special{papersize=210mm,297mm}
\usepackage[slide,algochapter,linesnumbered,algoruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{enumitem,IEEEtrantools,graphics,float,amsmath,amssymb,fullpage}
\usepackage{verbatim,tabularx,graphicx,setspace,sectsty,microtype}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,left=35mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[unicode,colorlinks,linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}
```

For some reason the `\WarningsOff*` and `\WarningFilter` commands of the `silence` package aren't working either. What am I doing wrong? How can I avoid these warnings?

Comment: `\special{papersize=210mm,297mm}`? Who told you that? Please trust in `geometry`.

Comment: The warning refers to hyperlinks generated by `hyperref`. When the pages to be referred to don't exist in your document, there really is no way to generate a link to them. So the warning is correct.

Comment: I'm using `biblatex` and coded this to get rid for the warnings of `\cite`s: ``\makeatletter
\if@partsw
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyperref=false}{biblatex}
\fi
\makeatother
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,sorting=none,doi=false,isbn=false,url=true,eprint=false,maxnames=10]{biblatex}`` It disables hyperlinks for citations when `\includeonly` is used.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Do you happen to know anything like this for BibTeX?

Comment: @MarioS.E.: No, sorry, I don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you seem to be using `\includeonly` only when you are working with just one chapter, you might not need any `hyperref` generated links at that time. So consider the `draft` package option.

Another clumsier possibility: write `\renewcommand`s (or wrappers) for macros from the `hyperref` package. Put them in your preamble right next to the `\includeonly` and you'll remember to comment that stuff out all together when you compile the whole thesis.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked perfectly.. didn't know that draft mode can suppress hyperlinks..

Out of curiosity though, could you be more descriptive about your second option?

Comment: @Berserker the second option is described in [http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2011-05/msg00234.html](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2011-05/msg00234.html) although I couldn't get it to work in your situation

Comment: Which are the macros we whould redefine?

Comment: @user4929 I can't answer for cmhughes (comment above). I think you redefine any macros that give you errors when you try to compile. If you have a problem that this answer can't solve you could post another question. Provide an MWE, and link to this post.

Answer (score 6):

This is a warning from the `hyperref` package.

The hyperlinks you create to other chapters don't exist when using `\includeonly`, but of course the reference itself is still valid.

You'll notice you don't get the warning when you compile the whole document together, because the hyperlinks *do* exist in this case.

Comment: I understand that, but is there any way that I can suppress the warning? I have too many inter-chapter references and those warnings kind of hide the ones I actually need to be concerned about. As I have already mentioned, I am not being able to do so using the silence package.

Answer (score 2):

I find this way very practical:

```
\includeonly{mainchapter} \hypersetup{draft}
```

So you can just comment/uncomment the whole line as you switch from full document to single chapter.