# Hyperlinks, theorems, enumerate, and autoref

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, autoref

Hyperlinks to theorem-like environments that begin with a nested `itemize` or `enumerate` are often broken (see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187647).
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\label{bigthm}
\begin{itemize}
\item A claim.
\item Another claim.
\end{itemize}
\end{theorem}

Let's prove Theorem~\ref{bigthm}.

\end{document}
```

This produces a warning:

```
pdfTeX warning (dest): name{theorem.1} has been
referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

and the hyperlink doesn’t work.

*(By the way, if we use `article` instead of `amsart`, then everything works as expected. What makes the AMS document class behave differently?)*

One solution is to add `\leavevmode` right after `\label{bigthm}`:

```
\begin{theorem}
\label{bigthm}\leavevmode
\begin{itemize}[...]
```

This fixes the hyperlink, but of course it also changes the formatting, which I don’t want.

A better solution (thanks, Simon!), which does not change the formatting, is to add `\phantomsection` right before `\label{bigthm}`:

```
\begin{theorem}
\phantomsection\label{bigthm}
\begin{itemize}[...]
```

Now everything works. Great!

**However**, this better solution does not work with `\autoref`, alas:

```
Let's prove~\autoref{bigthm}.
```

now produces `Let’s prove section 1.` (albeit with a working hyperlink).

So my question is this: Is there a way to fix the hyperlink that works with `\autoref` without changing the formatting?

Comment: Just try `\leavevmode\label{bigthm}`, without `\phantomsection`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer But that changes the formatting. I don’t want to start a new line.

Comment: Without `\leavevmode` the first item starts on the line of header line of the environment, which looks very ugly

Comment: I know, but that’s exactly where I need the first item to start. I don’t particularly like it either, but the house styles of some publishers don’t allow line breaks right after theorem headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A version with a `\fakephantomsection`, that uses `\@currenvir`, i.e. the current environment name in order to get the correct autoref name.

This is basically the same what `\phantomsection` does, but using the correct environment name.

The problem is known and mentioned in the documentation of `amsart`:

> • Other problems inherent in amsthm.
>
> ◦ Hyperlinking the first item
>   when a theorem begins with a list

```
\documentclass{amsart}



\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fakephantomsection}{%
  \Hy@MakeCurrentHref{\@currenvir.\the\Hy@linkcounter}
  \Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@anchorstart{\@currentHref}\hyper@anchorend}%
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\section{Foo}
\begin{theorem}
\fakephantomsection\label{bigthm}
\begin{itemize}
\item A claim.
\item Another claim.
\end{itemize}
\end{theorem}

Let's prove Theorem~\ref{bigthm} \autoref{bigthm}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great. Thank you so much, Christian! And thanks also for answering my other parenthetical question.

Comment: @MarcoVarisco: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!

Answer (score 1):

I am using this modification of the command proposed in the other answer:

```
\newcommand*{\fakephantomsection}{%
  \Hy@GlobalStepCount\Hy@linkcounter%
  \Hy@MakeCurrentHref{\@currenvir.\the\Hy@linkcounter}%
  \Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@anchorstart{\@currentHref}\hyper@anchorend}%
}
```