# Trying to fix warning: 'pdfTeX warning (dest): name{theorem.1} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one'

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, cross-referencing, enumerate, warnings

Here is a small MWE which creates a warning:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,refname={theorem,theorem},Refname={Theorem,Theorem}]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

\begin{theorem}
    \label{ABCtheorem}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item s
    \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

Theorem~\ref{ABCtheorem}

\end{document}
```

Compiling with Overleaf, the log file states that

> pdfTeX warning (dest): name{theorem.1} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one

This is confusing. The only reference that I have is `ABCtheorem` which is exactly the same in `\label{ABCtheorem}` as it is in `\ref{ABCtheorem}`. According to the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187647/116907) by [Poeh](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/56467/poeh), adding `\hspace{2em}` after `\label` removes the warning (and indeed it does). As does adding (any) text such as `xyz` after `\label`. And here, only ASCII characters are used.

But I would prefer to avoid adding unjustified snippets if possible. Is the problem that `enumerate` and `\label` are the only things inside `theorem`, and that this is 'incorrect'?

---

**Addendum**

Replacing `\label` with `\hypertarget` and `\ref` with `\hyperlink` also gives no warning.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,refname={theorem,theorem},Refname={Theorem,Theorem}]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

\begin{theorem}
    \hypertarget{ABCtheorem}{}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item s
    \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

Theorem~\hyperlink{ABCtheorem}{1}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

amsthm delays some code to the begin of the paragraph by putting it into \everypar. hyperref extends this code to create the anchor.

The problem is that enumerate sets \everypar too, and if the list is directly at the begin it overwrites the amsmath code before the anchor could be set.

The problem is known since a long time, see e.g. https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/48.

I think with the new para hooks in LaTeX it is possible to resolve the problem along the following lines, I will check if one can update hyperref to do this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument
 {
    \def\@thm#1#2#3{%
      \ifhmode
        \unskip\unskip\par
      \fi
      \normalfont
      \trivlist
      \let\thmheadnl\relax
      \let\thm@swap\@gobble
      \let\thm@indent\indent % indent
      \thm@headfont{\scshape}% heading font small caps
      \thm@notefont{\fontseries\mddefault\upshape}%
      \thm@headpunct{.}% add period after heading
      \thm@headsep 5\p@ plus\p@ minus\p@\relax
      \thm@space@setup
      #1% style overrides
      \@topsep \thm@preskip               % used by thm head
      \@topsepadd \thm@postskip           % used by \@endparenv
      \def\dth@counter{#2}%
      \ifx\@empty\dth@counter
        \def\@tempa{%
          \@oparg{\@begintheorem{#3}{}}[]%
        }%
      \else
        \H@refstepcounter{#2}%
        \hyper@makecurrent{#2}%
        \let\Hy@dth@currentHref\@currentHref
        \AddToHookNext{para/begin}{\MakeLinkTarget*{\Hy@dth@currentHref}}%
        \def\@tempa{%
          \@oparg{\@begintheorem{#3}{\csname the#2\endcsname}}[]%
        }%
      \fi
      \@tempa
    }%
  \dth@everypar={%
    \@minipagefalse \global\@newlistfalse
    \@noparitemfalse
    \if@inlabel
      \global\@inlabelfalse
      \begingroup \setbox\z@\lastbox
       \ifvoid\z@ \kern-\itemindent \fi
      \endgroup
      \unhbox\@labels
    \fi
    \if@nobreak \@nobreakfalse \clubpenalty\@M
    \else \clubpenalty\@clubpenalty \everypar{}%
    \fi
  }%
}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,refname={theorem,theorem},Refname={Theorem,Theorem}]{theorem}
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}


\chapter{Test chapter}
\begin{theorem}
    \label{ABCtheorem}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item s
    \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
    xxx\label{ABCtheorem2}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item s
    \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}


Theorem~\ref{ABCtheorem} \ref{ABCtheorem2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the reference to an earlier known instance of the problem, and the kind willingness to check if a solution can be integrated into the package `hyperref`!