# Silence warning about non-existing destination without disabling hyperref

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, include

**This is not a duplicate but a follow-up question to ["Reference does not exist" warning with \includeonly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52595/reference-does-not-exist-warning-with-includeonly).**

I use `\includeonly` to compile only part of my document. This causes `hyperref` to output a lot of warnings like

```
pdfTeX warning (dest): name{chapter.3} has been referenced but does not exist, 
replaced by a fixed one
```

In ["Reference does not exist" warning with \includeonly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52595/reference-does-not-exist-warning-with-includeonly) it was suggested to disable `hyperref` in order to silence the warning. However, since my chapters are quite long and I use `\eqref` extensively, I'd rather like `hyperref` to be enabled so that I can jump around the chapter as I write.

How can this be done? I did not get the `silence` package to filter out this warning message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The warning is directly thrown by pdfTeX. The TeX macro level is not involved, thus package like `silence` do not work for this case.

The warning can be suppressed by changing the source code of pdfTeX and recompiling.

Comment: With pdfTeX, you don't mean the pdfTeX-file, but actually the Tex-distribution?
How/Where can I change  the source-code of pdfTeX?
How can I recompile pdfTeX?

Comment: @JoKalliauer I meant the pdfTeX *binary* (program file). Sources, see [Development](http://www.tug.org/applications/pdftex/).